# Pages counts are showing in WordPress backend but pages shows 404

Tags: 404-error

I'm using WP latest version and suddenly I saw today all of my pages are shows 404.
It's working fine till yesterday. Here are screenshots that what happens to me.
[image]

What I have done :

All plugins are deactivated as shows in image.

Comment: try enabling page builder plugin. are you use wordpress.org platform or wp.com hosted one?

Comment: I don't think it will work as well I didn't used builder plugin for this website.

Comment: Edit wp-config.php to add  define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true); then hit this url database repair URL  your-site-name/wp-admin/maint/repair.php

Answer (score 0):

Kindly switch to any of the default themes and check if the issue persists, most of the times it solves the issue. If it does then there is some issue with the the theme you are using. Also make sure you are using latest php version. If even after switching the theme it doesn't work then you have make sure all plugins which you have installed (whether activated are not) are supported for the wordpress version you are using, try deleting all the plugins one by one and check simultaneously.

**Make sure you keep backup before doing anything**

Comment: this should be a comment instead of an answer